# Save button does not open xe:dialog box

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib, xpages-ssjs

It is pleasure to ask you directly as you are the one of the author of "Xpages Extension library: Step by Step Guide to the Next Generation of Xpage Component".

This is a link [Save button using SSJS does not open xe:dialog in web xpage but works on mobile xpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22771215/save-button-using-ssjs-does-not-open-xedialog-in-web-xpage-but-works-on-mobile) to a posted question.

In the above post save button is making sure that field has value based on the value of another field. If that field is blank, then this field must have value.

I also tried field validation with computed required value based on another field but that is also not working. Here is a code:

```
var checkBox31:com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspInputCheckbox = getComponent("checkBox31");
if (checkBox31.getValue()== '' | checkBox31.getValue()== null){
return true;
}
{
return false;
}
```

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Best regards,
Mohan Gangan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As posted in the duplicate question, the checkbox has a value of 'true' or 'false'.

```
var checkBox31:com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspInputCheckbox = getComponent("checkBox31");
if (checkBox31 != null && checkBox31.getValue()== 'false'){
    return true;
}else{
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Hi Brian, the above solution worked like a charm in validation. Thank you very much.

Comment: That's good. In that case it is best to mark the answer as accepted

Comment: Accepted the above solution.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

    To accept an answer:

    Choose one answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem.
    To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.
    You may change which answer is accepted, or simply un-accept the answer, at any time.

Comment: Your code works perfectly. Thanks again for your valuable time.

Comment: Mohan, what I mean is that since you are happy with the answer, click the grey arrow beside my answer. This marks the answer as "accepted"